# Push multiple elements to array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to push multiple elements as one array, but getting an error:

```
> a = []
[]
> a.push.apply(null, [1,2])
TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined
```

I'm trying to do similar stuff that I'd do in ruby, I was thinking that `apply` is something like `*`.

```
>> a = []
=> []
>> a.push(*[1,2])
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Your example was almost correct, it only required to put `a` in place of `null`, like this: `a.push.apply(a, [1,2])`

Answer (score 317, accepted):

When using most functions of objects with `apply` or `call`, the `context` parameter MUST be the object you are working on.

In this case, you need `a.push.apply(a, [1,2])` (or more correctly `Array.prototype.push.apply(a, [1,2])`)

Comment: Is there a limit to how many elements can be pushed with this method? I know JavaScript has an argument limit, is this the case when using the "apply" function?

Comment: I believe it's 65,535 in older browsers, practically unlimited (4B) in modern ones.

Comment: The limit is pretty low in node (v20.4.0) with default settings. I didn't find the exact value but it's somewhere between 1<<16 and 1<<17.

Answer (score 872):

You can push multiple elements into an array in the following way

```js
var a = [];
    
a.push(1, 2, 3);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: This answer and the selected answer produce different, and perhaps unexpected, results. a.push(1) vs. a.push([1])

Comment: Can anyone explain, why this has so many more votes than the accepted answer? It might be easier, but is less flexible. If you want to merge 2 arrays, this wont work.

Comment: @BluE if you want to merge two arrays just use array.concat()

Comment: @FlorentArlandis array.concat does not work to add the 2nd array to the first. It will create a new one. I know it is similar. The spread operator is what I was looking for. Just look at the other answers and comments there for details.

Comment: @BluE ES6 now allow you to do something like this ```array1.push(...array2)``` that works exactly like ```array1.push(array2[0], array2[1], array2[2])``` except a limitation of number of elements in array2 (about 100,000)

Answer (score 703):

Now in ECMAScript2015 (a.k.a. ES6), you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to append multiple items at once:

```js
var arr = [1];
var newItems = [2, 3];
arr.push(...newItems);
console.log(arr);
```

See [Kangax's ES6 compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) table to see what browsers are compatible

Comment: whaaaaaaat this is awesome, plus, if you do it in typescript it will compile to push.apply so you have backward compatibility

Comment: This has array size limitation. Try with big arrays. You will get exception.

Comment: I wanted to know more about the size limitation so I tried it. `a = []; b = []; for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { b.push(i); } a.push(...(b.slice(0, 130000)));` This indeed causes an error for me. "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" The limit may depend on the size of elements in the array, not just the number of elements. That's just a guess. It may depend on the environment. Also just a guess. I haven't tried looking for documentation.

Comment: What about the performance of this operation vs using each element separately?

Answer (score 96):

As one alternative, you can use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var result = a.concat(b);
```

This would create and return a new array instead of pushing items to the same array. It can be useful if you don't want to modify the source array but rather make a shallow copy of it.

Comment: Array.prototype.concat returns new array.

Comment: He wants to push to existing array so `Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2)` is the correct answer, because using `arr1.concat(arr2)` you are creating a new array.

Comment: @suricactus `arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2)` is not a big deal and looks much cleaner. Pushing to old array or replacing old array with the new one depends on your needs. If you deal with 10m+ elements pushing to old array will work faster, if you manage small chunks you hardly find any difference in speed. Both options a completely legit.

Comment: Are you guys sure `prototype.push.apply` works faster than `.concat`?
I think `apply` might actually be slower, since it probably calls `push` again and again  for each item in `arr2`

Comment: @YuvalA. `prototype.push.apply` only calls `push` once. And the distinction above isn't necessary about speed but an in-place operation vs creating a new array. What if I had a method that took an array and was supposed to modify it in-place? The `concat` method cannot possibly work, even with VisionN's code as it won't modify the variable for the caller of the function.

Comment: Not considering the fact it does not A the Q, I want to add that the reason using `.concat` is 'slow', or inefficient, especially with large arrays, is because the VM will need to GC the old array, impacting performance considerably.

Comment: @origo Are you sure about that? Optimisation mechanisms are not that stupid and may "understand" your intensions. For example, the best way to append values to array (slice) in Golang is doing `a = append(a, 1, 2, 3)`, although internally `append` will always return a new slice. Same may work in JS, as the new array will immediately replace the old one in memory. Anyway, this is all theory, we need JSPerf here to prove the word "considerably". And yes, it does A the Q, as it does exactly what is required, if used as `a = a.concat([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: ```a = a.concat(b)``` is still a shorter syntax than ```Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2)```

Comment: Please do not treat `a = a.concat` as equivalent to `push`. This does not just come down to syntax preference, it is not the same operation. Using concat only updates a *single* reference to the array (`a`). If there any other references to the same array anywhere else in your app, they will *not* see the update. If the goal is to update an array rather than work with a new one, always use `push`.

Comment: @nmclean This answer is so old that I have almost forgotten about it. I have updated it and included a note, so it's obvious to everyone that these two methods are not equivalent.

Answer (score 29):

If you want an alternative to `Array.concat` in ECMAScript 2015 (a.k.a. ES6, ES2015) that, like it, does not modify the array but returns a new array you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) like so:

```js
var arr = [1];
var newItems = [2, 3];
var newerItems = [4, 5];
var newArr = [...arr, ...newItems, ...newerItems];
console.log(newArr);
```

Note this is different than the `push` method as the `push` method mutates/modifies the array.

If you want to see if certain ES2015 features work in your browser check [Kangax's compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

You can also use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or a similar transpiler if you do not want to wait for browser support and want to use ES2015 in production.

Answer (score 4):

Easier way is

```
a = []
a.push(1,2,3)
```

Another way is

```
a = [...a, 4,5,6]
```

if you want to create another array

```
const b = a.concat(7,8,9)
```

Comment: Easier than what? These are the exact approaches given in [this 10 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14723896/1255289) and [this 7 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35167699/1255289)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same doubt and in my case, an easier solution worked for me:

```
let array = []
array.push(1, 2, 4, "string", new Object())
console.log(array)
// logs [ 1, 2, 4, 'string', {} ]
```

Comment: Easier than what? This is the exact approach given in [this 10 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14723896/1255289)

Comment: Does copying the same comment over and over give you points? I try to contribute, others...

Answer (score 0):

Pushing multiple objects at once often depends on how are you declaring your `array`.

This is how I did

```
//declaration
productList = [] as any;
```

now `push` records

```
this.productList.push(obj.length, obj2.length, items);
```

Comment: "Type assertion expressions can only be used in TypeScript files." is what VS Code said about the keyword `any` here

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have an `array of first ten numbers` but missing a number, `say 6`.
You can insert it into the array at the index `5` with the following code

```js
function insert(array, index, obj) {
  return [...array.slice(0,index), obj, ...array.slice(index)]
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,0]
arr = insert(arr, 5, 6)
console.log(arr)
```