# push.apply() not increasing array size

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have this piece of code

```
if ($scope.newLeverAdded) {
    console.log("executed this");
    console.log($scope.tradeDataObj, "data is here");
    console.log($scope.group_levers, "this 2 here");
    $scope.group_levers.levers.push.apply($scope.group_levers.levers, $scope.tradeDataObj.levers[0]);

    console.log($scope.group_levers, "mid prrinting");
    console.log("after this");
}
console.log($scope.group_levers, "final prrinting");
```

All i am trying is to increase my Array size by adding new element to it.. SO that now the array contains 2 element. But the final console still returns a single element in array.

Why is it so?

Comment: What is your complete console output?

Comment: 2nd argument to `apply` need to be an array. Is `$scope.tradeDataObj.levers[0]` is an array?

Comment: Why are you using `apply`? Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: No..there is no specific reason. All I need is to preserve previous array data and push new data..so that I can send complete JSON back to server. I would really appreciate if some one could illustrate when is the need for .apply() withpush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
$scope.group_levers.levers.push.apply($scope.group_levers.levers, $scope.tradeDataObj.levers);
```

The second argument of [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) should be an array.

I assume that you are trying to push multiple items like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14723909/887149) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4156156/887149)

Comment: Mohayemin..thanx for pointing to right direction. I guessed, if the original source is array, only object should be added to it not the array again. Hence was doing levers[0]. Is this specifically the case fr apply

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to run your code, here's a couple of things you can try:

1. it could be that your code is not entering the condition that you have specified.
2. why not just test with a `$scope.group_levers.levers.push('new element')` instead of the apply

Comment: Wierdly..when i tried .push($scope.tradeDataObj.levers[0]). The IDE throws syntax error sayong expected identifier

Comment: I am assuming `$scope.group_levers.levers` is an array.

Comment: Ya that surely an array...Thats why it was weird to see such response from IDE. Visual Studio, if that matters