# Push method insert nested records

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two array objects & wanted to merge these.But for some reason it gets inserted one level below of first array

```
let first = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'}];
let first2 = [{name:'aa'},{name:'bb'}];
first.push(first2);
```

now if I print first object, it gives below output

```
[{name: "a"},{name: "b"},[ {name: "aa"}, {name: "bb"}]]
```

whereas I need this output`[ {name: "a"}, {name: "b"}, {name: "aa"}, {name: "bb"}]`

Answer (score 2):

[Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the `first2` array to push the items instead of the whole array:

```js
let first = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'}];
let first2 = [{name:'aa'},{name:'bb'}];
first.push(...first2);

console.log(first);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about `.push()`, but another way that I prefer to use in these situations is the `.concat()` method. One potential advantage to using `.concat()` is that you don't modify `first` or `first2`, instead creating a new array. This is useful if you are programming in a functional & immutable style for libraries such as Redux.

```
let first = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'}];
let first2 = [{name:'aa'},{name:'bb'}];
let both = [].concat(first, first2);

console.log(both);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're pushing an array, into another array. `.push()` adds an item into an array, so it treats the entire array as one item.

The easiest thing to do is to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14723909/4875631), or use the new ES6 spread syntax, that @Ori points out in his answer:

```js
let first = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'}];
let first2 = [{name:'aa'},{name:'bb'}];
first.push.apply(first, first2);

console.log(first);
```