# How can I refactor adding const object names into the array?

Tags: javascript

My code is working, but it looks very creepy.

```
ar2.push(pr1);ar2.push(pr2);ar2.push(pr3);ar2.push(pr4);ar2.push(pr5);ar2.push(pr6);
```

basically all those pr1, pr2 things are declared const... I was trying to add them to the array using a for loop, to no avail. Is there any way to do a one liner for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [push multiple elements to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723848/push-multiple-elements-to-array)

Comment: If the variables `pr1, pr2, ...` are declared with `var` instead of `const`, you will be able to use a loop. However, you will have to trade off the properties that `const` gives to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

`push` accepts multiple parameters, so you can just list them all when you `push`:

```
ar2.push(pr1, pr2, pr3, pr4, pr5, pr6);
```

That said, it's a *bit* of a code smell to have so many standalone variable names - if possible, you might consider modifying your code such that the `pr`s are defined in an array to begin with, rather than `push`ing afterwards.

Comment: But it's still too long though. Is there any way to iterate/loop through the names? I was trying to use both ++ and ${``} to no avail..

Comment: Ideally, change your code so that the `pr`s are all in an array *initially*, rather than `push`ing after the fact, though without seeing the context of how the `pr`s are defined, it's hard to say (feel free to edit that into your quesiton)

Comment: Opinion-based, but I completely disagree. Mutation should be avoided when not necessary - code is easier to reason about when objects don't change after they're declared.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Array.prototype.push.apply`:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(ar2, [pr1, pr2, pr3, pr4, pr5, pr6]);
```