# Push objects keys' values into an array

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
{
  "PAV-001": {
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku1": {},
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku2": {},
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku4": {},
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku5": {}
  },
  "P-001": {
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku1": {}
  },
  "PAV-002": {
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku1": {},
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku3": {},
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku4": {},
    "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku6": {}
  }
}
```

I want to store PAV-001's values(like:"09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku1" these) into an array, I tried: `arr1.push(Object.keys(data[value]))`
But it doesn't work, how to address this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [push multiple elements to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723848/push-multiple-elements-to-array)

Comment: Could you please also add full example of arr1.push ... method that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spread the the array obtained by Object.keys method and pass that to push method of the array like

```
arr1.push(...Object.keys(data[value]));
```

or you can use `Array.prototype.concat` method and assign the value back to the array like

```
arr1 = arr1.concat(Object.keys(data[value]));
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now, but can I ask why does the spread syntax work? Or what does it do for this?

Comment: Spread syntax usage in this will pass the arguments to push as comma separated values rather than an array

Answer (score 0):

For values of a single key :

```
const object = {
    "PAV-001": {
        "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku1": {},
        "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku2": {},
        "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku4": {},
        "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku5": {}
    },
}

let myArray = []
Object.keys(object["PAV-001"]).forEach(key => myArray.push(key))
```

Or for the all values of all keys of `object`

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(_object => Object.keys(object[_object]).forEach(key => myArray.push(key)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can use Object.keys() which returns an array whose elements are strings. then just use map to map each key as a value to an array.

```js
    const obj = {
        "PAV-001": {
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku1": {},
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku2": {},
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku4": {},
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku5": {}
        },
        "P-001": {
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku1": {}
       },
       "PAV-002": {
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku1": {},
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku3": {},
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku4": {},
          "09SGH6eBNbRpFw9WnHdQO1mYcku6": {}
       }
}

var arr = Object.keys(obj["PAV-001"]).map((key) => key);
console.log(arr)
```