# Add array to multidimensional array using js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add to existing array

```js
var value_list = [
    ["asdf：4sdf", "", "", "", "asf：sadf", "", "", "", "sadf：2000/01/3", "", "", "", ""],
    ["safd", "asfd", "sdaf", "sadf", "asdf", "asdf", "sdf", "asfd", "sadf", "dsf", "sdf", "adf", "sadf"],
    ["1", "asdf", "asdf", "22", "22", "3000", "500", "0", "0", "3500", "0", "3500", ""],
    ["2", "asdf", "asdf", "22", "22", "3000", "500", "0", "0", "3500", "0", "3500", ""],
];
```

new array:

```js
["SELECTIONS: ", "", str, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Final result:

```js
var value_list = [
    ["SELECTIONS: ", "", str, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["asdf：4sdf", "", "", "", "asf：sadf", "", "", "", "sadf：2000/01/3", "", "", "", ""],
    ["safd", "asfd", "sdaf", "sadf", "asdf", "asdf", "sdf", "asfd", "sadf", "dsf", "sdf", "adf", "sadf"],
    ["1", "asdf", "asdf", "22", "22", "3000", "500", "0", "0", "3500", "0", "3500", ""],
    ["2", "asdf", "asdf", "22", "22", "3000", "500", "0", "0", "3500", "0", "3500", ""],
];
```

Tried `var value_list = [new_array,value_list]` but no success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push multiple elements to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723848/push-multiple-elements-to-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new array elements at the beginning of an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: You just need to do `[newArray, ...value_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably what you want to do:

OPTION 1 – My personal choice

```
var result = [new_array, ...value_list]
```

OPTION 2

```
value_list.unshift(new_array)
```

Comment: Tried let value_selections = ["SELECTIONS: ", "", str, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
var value_list =    value_list.unshift(value_selections); and gives me number? did i miss something ?

Comment: @NickPietrushka `unshift()` alters the array _in-place_ and returns the number of elements in the modified array. So don't use the return value, use the array itself. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

Comment: @Ivar could you please provide an example, used     console.log(value_list.unshift(value_selections)); still number, one thing i need to put this array to variable

Comment: @NickPietrushka I edited my comment and added a link. By console logging you _still_ use the return value of  `.unshift()`. Put the `.unshift()` on a separate line and then only log `value_list`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Array method `unshift` will help you.

```
value_list.unshift(new_array)
```

Read about it here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp

Answer (score -1):

I think
`value_list.push(["SELECTIONS: ", "", str, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""])`
should just work fine.

Comment: Hey – Push will add it to the end, I think his specific use case wants it at the start

Answer (score -1):

This is the quick modern way:

```
let a = [1,2,3];
let b = [4,5,6];
let c = [...a,...b];
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do

```
[new_array, ...value_list]
```

instead

```
[new_array,value_list]
```

```js
var value_list = [
  [
    "asdf：4sdf",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "asf：sadf",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "sadf：2000/01/3",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
  ],
  [
    "safd",
    "asfd",
    "sdaf",
    "sadf",
    "asdf",
    "asdf",
    "sdf",
    "asfd",
    "sadf",
    "dsf",
    "sdf",
    "adf",
    "sadf",
  ],
  [
    "1",
    "asdf",
    "asdf",
    "22",
    "22",
    "3000",
    "500",
    "0",
    "0",
    "3500",
    "0",
    "3500",
    "",
  ],
  [
    "2",
    "asdf",
    "asdf",
    "22",
    "22",
    "3000",
    "500",
    "0",
    "0",
    "3500",
    "0",
    "3500",
    "",
  ],
];

const new_array = [
  "SELECTIONS: ",
  "",
  "str",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
];

value_list = [new_array, ...value_list];
console.log(value_list);
```